# Can parameters from a parametrized class be used in external function definitions?

Tags: system-verilog

Say I have a parametrized class `foo` and in it a simple setter.

```
class foo #(type T = int);
    T member;

    extern function T get_member();
endclass
```

If I try to define this function outside of class scope, I get an unknown type error for T.

```
function T foo::get_member();
    return member;
endfunction
```

Fair enough, you'd get the same error in C++ (from which SV seems to have inherited much of the template/parametrization mechanism). So, in C++, you solve this by providing the template declaration before your function definition, so said template can be recognized by the compiler. Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
function T foo::get_member();
    return member;
endfunction
```

Does a similar mechanism exist in SystemVerilog, and if so, what is it? If it doesn't then it's pretty clear I must define all my parametrized functions/tasks within the class body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the scope to access the parameter type, change `T` to `foo::T` in the external function definition.

```
function foo::T foo::get_member();
    return member;
endfunction
```

Working example [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Zz)

Comment: thanks, that works. a little verbose for my taste, i would have preferred the c++ way of doing it.

Comment: @stellarossa You could do '  \`define T foo::T  ' to make it a little less verbose. But watch out for polluting your global space; pair it with a '  \`undef T  '